# How to include an array of packet pointers in a packet in OmNET++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am defining a custom packet in OmNET++. The start point is a custom message I define in `CustomMessage.msg`:

```
packet CustomMessage {
    int field;
}
```

Then I have `BundleMessage` which should be something like:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "CustomMessage_m.h"
typedef CustomMessage* CustomMessagePtr;
}}
packet CustomMessage;
class noncobject CustomMessagePtr;

packet BundleMessage {
    CustomMessagePtr[] messages;
}
```

The attempt is somewhat clear. I am trying to enable `BundleMessage` to store an array of pointers to many `CustomMessage`.

Of course it is not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In definition of `BundleMessage` it should be:

```
CustomMessagePtr messages[];
```